# Java 6 Collections.checkedList appropriate usage

Tags: java, inheritance

I am creating several functions in which I want to return the interface instead of the implementation, I.E. List instead of ArrayList .  My method signature and a brief implementation follows:

```
public List<MyAwesomeComposedObject> convert(Collection<MyAwesomeObject> awesomeObjects>)
{
    List<MyAwesomeComposedObject> composedObjects = new ArrayList<MyAwesomeComposedObject>();
    for(MyAwesomeObject awesomeObject : awesomeObjects)
    {
        MyAwesomeComposedObject composedObject = new MyAwesomeComposedObject(awesomeObject);
        composedObjects.add(composedObject);
    }

    List<MyAwesomeComposedObject> composedObjectList = Collections.checkedList<composedObjects, MyAwesomeComposedObject.class);
    return composedObjectList;
}
```

My question is, is this an antipattern of some sort?  I want to guarantee that the invoker of this method is getting the interface instead of an implementation.  I also do not believe this to be a case of overengineering.  If this is not the correct way to return an interface, in this scenario I am open to the correct implementation.

Attached is a small program that results in an exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Vector v = (Vector) c();
}

static List<Object> c()
{
    List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
    l.add(new Object());
    List<Object> o = Collections.checkedList(l, Object.class);
    return o;
}
```

The javadoc is here: [checked list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: I don't see what the issue is; the method signature guarantees the caller is getting a `List<Foo>` by definition.

Comment: I have updated my question, Vector implements the List interface, this code above fails.

Comment: It fails because an `ArrayList` is not a `Vector`. This is why coders should not cast from an interface to a concrete type unless they are absolutely sure that the instance is truly an instance of the concrete type. There is no way to prevent people from doing ill-advised things like the above except education.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem or the question is. The above (edited) code fails because `c` returns an instance of `ArrayList`, and `main` casts it to a `Vector`. `ArrayList` is not a subclass of `Vector`, so this results in a `ClassCastException`. Why is this a problem? What do you want to happen here?

Comment: @TomAnderson definitely a case of me overanalyzing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your revised question: There is no way to prevent the caller from attempting to cast to whatever they want. If it is an inappropriate cast they will get the exception. This is the very reason why casting from an interface to a concrete class is strongly discouraged.

If you are really worried about this, consider returning an `ArrayList` instead of a `List`. That should discourage casting since they are getting a concrete type. Please note that I do not endorse this, it is just an option.

> I want to guarantee that the invoker of this method is getting the interface instead of an implementation

This is not valid. You are returning a `List` where the declared type of the elements is an interface, however each element must be SOME instantiation. All a checked collection does is prevent the addition of elements of the incorrect type. There is nothing that prevents the user from casting back to the implementation type.

If you are attempting to ensure that the user gets `List` instead of `ArrayList` (my assumption here because I don't see an interface for you Awesome class), this again is flawed because the user could still cast the `List` to an `ArrayList` although this would be a bad idea since it risks a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Correct each element must be some instantiation, I am referring to the implementation of the `collection` . I want to be able to avoid a class cast exception if it gets fed into a Vector or any other List implementation.

Comment: thanks for the update.  I also want to avoid having ArrayList in the signature.  Based on Peter's answer it would seem possible that my approach may work, I want to know if I am looking at it in the completely wrong light.  I am starting to believe that I may very well be doing so.

Comment: Yes, I think you are. There is nothing you can do to return an interface and prevent a user from attempting to cast it to whatever they want. Just as I could do the following `Vector v = (Vector)((List) new ArrayList());`

Answer (score 2):

The List returned is a Collections.CheckedList not a Vector. You cannot the reference to a type the object is not.

However what you can do is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>(c());
}
```

---

composedObjects is already a List, you can return that.

```
public List<MyAwesomeComposedObject> convert(Collection<MyAwesomeObject> awesomeObjects>)  {  
   List<MyAwesomeComposedObject> composedObjects = new ArrayList<MyAwesomeComposedObject>();  
   for(MyAwesomeObject awesomeObject : awesomeObjects)    
        composedObjects.add(new MyAwesomeComposedObject(awesomeObject));  
   return composedObjects;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question to show the exception I want to avoid, which in turn may mean I asked the question incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the update Peter.  Is my approach valid then to rely on the Collections.checkedList method?

Comment: checkedList is useful for runtime checking that the types of added entries are correct. You don't appear to have this problem in your example.

Answer (score 0):

No, I recommend to keep the code as simple as possible. Read the Javadoc for a discussion when to use Collections.checkedList

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class%29